# On which day the pond will fill half?

Tags: mathematics

> A pond has flowers in it each day the flowers in the pond get doubled if the pond gets full-on 20th day, on which day the pond will fill half? How?

We are sitting here in the office in a group and the source is one of my friends

Comment: it seems like that this puzzle comes from elsewhere. please provide the source. unattributed work may get downvoted or even closed. happy puzzling ;)

Comment: Ohh Yes. We are sitting here in the office in a group and the source is one of my friends. Happy puzzling :)

Comment: Good job @OmegaKrypton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer

> the 19th day

Explanation

> Pond gets full (volume = 1 pond) on 20th day. One day before, pond is 1*1/2 = half pond full